# Fetch vs. XMLHttpRequest reliability

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I'm not able to find out, why XMLHttpRequest works and using the fetch or axiom does not work. The endpoint is constant.
Here is the code to compare ...
XMLHttpRequest actually returns the text, 
fetch does not return anything

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest()
    r.open('GET', 'http://localhost:1337/ticks', true)
    r.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (r.readyState !== 4 || r.status !== 200) {
            return
        }
    }
    r.send()

    fetch('http://localhost:1337/ticks', {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'no-cors'
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response.text()
            }).then(function (text) {
                console.log(text)
    }).catch(function (error) {
    })
```

Comment: That code is broken. Did you try and `console.log(response)` in your fetch callback?

Comment: sure, I attached breakpoints and the response.ok in fetch is false, so the call fails, however, in the very same run, the xmlhttprequest works juts fine

Comment: code is not broken ;)

Comment: You may need `credentials: "same-origin"` in the `fetch` settings. Check the Network tab in the dev tools. Are there any differences in the request / response headers or bodies?

Comment: In the network tab, the response looks very ok, with the content it should have for both cases (fetch and xmlhttprequest). so the network layer works.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this:

> ```
> mode: 'no-cors'
> ```

It tells fetch that you want to make the request (to tell the server something) but don't want to read the response (which might be forbidden by the Same Origin Policy). This setting lets you do that without throwing the error you would normally get. Since you said you don't want to read the response, fetch doesn't try to make the response available to you.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the mode: 'no-cors' actually brings the body of the response to life. Just in case somebody has the same problem... 
So there is still a question why fetch works this way, cause the no-cors
is pretty much useless, when you get no response body with it.